# What does "vtable fixup" mean?

Tags: c++, vtable, fixup

I have heard this term, "vtable fixup", used. What does it mean? I had no success asking Google. I already know what a vtable is so that does not need to be defined.

Comment: This sounds compiler specific.  Post more information about the circumstances where you are seeing this and you might get a better response.

Comment: VTable have nothing to do with C++. Some compilers use them to implement C++ features but without more context there is no real answer to the question.

Comment: I have heard it used in the context of reconstructing data of a polymorphic type (on one platform) on another platform that may not support polymorphism or may have a different memory layout, different word sizes, etc. Is it just a general term for "getting polymorphic types one platform to work on another when the data is serialized from one platform to another"?

Comment: from your description it is a general term for "we didn't serialize our data in a platform independant way, we moved it to another platform, and now we're stuck."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer: It's a hack to allow code generated by different compilers / languages to coexist. It allows the runtime to find the locations of virtual functions without knowing the details of the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

For me, [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q="vtable+fixup") revealed that vtable fixups are a special feature of the PE (Windows) executable file format. They provide an efficient way of implementing vtables (for C++ and other languages), according to [ECMA's PE spec](http://jilc.sourceforge.net/ecma_p2_cil.shtml#_Toc524940658):

> Certain languages, which choose not to
>   follow the common type system runtime
>   model, may have virtual functions
>   which need to be represented in a
>   v-table.  These v-tables are laid out
>   by the compiler, not by the runtime. 
>   Finding the correct v-table slot and
>   calling indirectly through the value
>   held in that slot is also done by the
>   compiler. The VtableFixups field in
>   the runtime header contains the
>   location and size of an array of
>   Vtable Fixups (see clause 14.5.1).
>   V-tables shall be emitted into a
>   read-write section of the PE file.
>
> Each entry in this array describes a
>   contiguous array of v-table slots of
>   the specified size.  Each slot starts
>   out initialized to the metadata token
>   value for the method they need to
>   call.  At image load time, the runtime
>   Loader will turn each entry into a
>   pointer to machine code for the CPU
>   and can be called directly.